# Vue: Populate form after a axios call

Tags: vue.js, axios

I am working on editing and I have following code so far.

```
<template>
   <base-layout :layout-classes="layoutClasses">
      <div class="container mt-3">
         <div v-if="storing">
            <h3>Please wait....</h3>
         </div>
         <div class="content">
            <base-block rounded title="Create Data">
               <b-form @submit.prevent="UpdateData" class="mb-5">
              <b-form-group label-cols-sm="2" label="Name">
                <b-form-input v-model="form.name" class="form-control-alt" type="text" placeholder="Name"></b-form-input>
              </b-form-group>
              <b-form-group label="Image" label-cols-sm="2">
                <b-form-file plain v-on:change="onFileChange($event, 'image')"></b-form-file>
              </b-form-group>
              <b-form-group label="" label-cols-sm="2">
                    <b-button type="submit" class="text-white" variant="dark">Submit</b-button>
              </b-form-group>
            </b-form>
            </base-block>
         </div>
      </div>
   </base-layout>
</template>
<script>
   import BaseLayout from '../layouts/Base/Base.vue'
   export default {
        data () {
            return {
                form: {
                    name: '',
                    image: null
                },
                storing: false,
                layoutClasses: {
                   sideOverlay: true,
                   sidebar: true,
                   header: true,
                   footer: true
                }
            }
        },
        components: {
            BaseLayout
        },

        methods: {
            onFileChange(e, key){
                let formData = new FormData();
                formData.append('file', e.target.files[0]);
                formData.append('dir', 'datas');
                axios.post('/uploads', formData, {
                    headers: { 'content-type': 'multipart/form-data' }
                })
                .then(({data}) => {
                    this.form[key] = data.data.path
                })
                .catch(err => {
                    Object.assign(this.errors, {}, err.response.data.errors)
                })
            },
        },
        mounted() {
            axios.get('/datas/' + this.$route.params.id).then(response => {
                this.name = response.data.data.name
                console.log(response)
            })
            .catch(err => {
                // console.log('GET_Data_FAIL', err.response)
            })
            .finally(() => {
                this.storing = false
            })
        }
   }
</script>
```

On the `mounted` I am receiving data which needs to be edited. Now I want to populate the fields with the data I am receiving after axios. I tried doing `this.name = response.data.data.name` but that is not working I guess. What is best way to get this done? And is it possible to use addData form for updating also like we can do it with laravel view blade?

Comment: What's the error message in your console?

Comment: @Abregre There is no error actually. But the form is also not populated

Comment: I am not familiar with the options API but shouldnt it be `this.form.name = response.data.data.name;`?